# Event Receiver to generate random number on newform.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

I have SharePoint Online site with a list having dropdown.And when I select any option dropdown,I need to generate the random number.Can any one help me what event receiver should I use and how can I achieve this.

Comment: How that random number will be used or stored after the creation ?

Can you give any example for the same ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you use SharePoint 2013 or SharePoint Online.

With SharePoint CSR you can add a JavaScript to a form and completely override the rendering (HTML creation) of the fields on a form. You can add functionality, effects and change field behaviors.

Look here for an introduction and some samples
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a

Concerning your random number. Below you find a sample of similar functionality that I had to build once.

For every new item I needed to create a unique random title 'New Contract 1234-12345678-....'. When saving the generated value was stored in the SharePoint item.  When editing the item I set the title field to read-only.

I don't remember if I put this script on the form itself or if I registered it in the JSLink property of the field.

You can find more information about this by googling on 'SharePoint CSR' (Client Side Rendering)

Hope it helps.

```
(function () {
    (window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"><\/script>'));

    var myOverrides = {};
    myOverrides.Templates = {};

    myOverrides.Templates.Fields = {
        "MyInternalFieldName": {
            "NewForm": FillDefaultTitle
            "EditForm": MakeReadOnly,
        }
    };

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(myOverrides);
})();


function FillDefaultTitle(ctx) {
    var formCtx = SPClientTemplates.Utility.GetFormContextForCurrentField(ctx);

    // Generate guid
    var guid1 = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function (c) {
        var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8);
        return v.toString(16);
    });

    // Set the title
    var theValue = "New contract " + guid1;
    formCtx.registerGetValueCallback(formCtx.fieldName, function () {
        return theValue;
    });

    $('nobr:contains("Name")').closest('tr').hide();

    return "<div class='mjhCustomField' style='display:none' >" + theValue + "</div>";
}

function MakeReadOnly(ctx) {
    var formCtx = SPClientTemplates.Utility.GetFormContextForCurrentField(ctx);

    var field = ctx.CurrentFieldSchema;
    var fieldTitle = field.Title;
    var fieldValue = ctx.CurrentItem.FileLeafRef;

    // return our own HTML implementation of the field on the form.
    return "<div class='mjhCustomField' >" + fieldValue + "</div>";
}
```

Comment: I guess this script will have to be added in the JSLink for the form.